Can we set a Thread Local variable from child class and access it in the parent class in Java?
I have an automation project with two Test classes(child classes) and a TestBase (parent class). In the TestBase I have a threadlocal attribute defined as below.
protected ThreadLocal<ITestContext> iTestContextThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();


In each of the child class I'm setting an attribute called 'feature' into this ThreadLocal attribute. Sample Child class looks like below.
public class RestTests extends TestBase{

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void init(ITestContext iTestContext) {
        iTestContext.setAttribute("feature", "Sample - RestTests1");
        iTestContextThreadLocal.set(iTestContext);
        String feature = iTestContextThreadLocal.get().getAttribute("feature").toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void testScenario1(){
        //Automation Code
    }
}

In the TestBase I have an 'AfterMethod' inside which I try to access this value set in child class's before Method.
    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void test() {
        try {
            ITestContext iTestContext = iTestContextThreadLocal.get();
            String feature = iTestContext.getAttribute("feature").toString();
            System.out.println("***** ThreadLocalAttribute: " + feature);

            //Rest of the code
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Clean up the ThreadLocal variables after method execution
            iTestContextThreadLocal.remove();
        }
    }

The Issue I'm facing is - in parallel Test execution (in both classes and methods) feature set in one class is provided as the output.
As an example if I set 'Sample - RestTests1' and 'Sample - RestTests2' as features in my child classes, when I try to access them in TestBase afterMethod using the below code, only one class's feature is given
iTestContext.getAttribute("feature").toString();

How to fix this and get feature set in each class via TestBase's AfterMethod ?
I have tried changing the order of annotations and trying out the solutions in the internet. But no fix is found yet.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

If you read, for example, this question on a similar topic, you'll see that there is a problem with TestNG's policy of creating only one instance per test class, and how to reset state if the test should be run in parallell.
I guess that in your case, you shouldn't have made the init method @BeforeClass, but rather @BeforeMethod, or perhaps @BeforeTest (don't remember the exact names).

A couple of things to remember:

TestNG guarantees that two TestNG methods (configuration method and test method) run in the same thread (during parallel execution) only when it involves @BeforeMethod - @Teset - @AfterMethod combination. For no other combination of a configuration method + test method this assurance is provided. So relying on ThreadLocal will work ONLY for this combination.
ITestContext represents a TestNG java object that is associated with the current <test> tag. So you will have only one object for all the @Test methods within a current <test> tag.
You should instead be using an ITestResult object which is unique for every @Test method.

Here's a cleaned up version of the same sample that shows how to do this.
Base class
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

public class TestBase {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(ITestResult itrOfTestMethod) {
        String feature = "RestTests-" + UUID.randomUUID();
        itrOfTestMethod.setAttribute("feature", feature);
        ITestResult itrOfConfigMethod = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        log(itrOfTestMethod, methodType(itrOfConfigMethod), name(itrOfConfigMethod));
    }

    protected static String name(ITestResult tr) {
        return tr.getMethod().getMethodName();
    }

    protected static void log(ITestResult tr, String type, String methodName) {
        String feature = Optional.ofNullable(
                        tr.getAttribute("feature")
                ).orElse("undefined")
                .toString();
        String msg = "Feature name in " + type + " annotated " + methodName + "() = " + feature
                + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.err.println(msg);
    }

    protected String methodType(ITestResult tr) {
        ITestNGMethod method = tr.getMethod();
        if (method.isBeforeMethodConfiguration()) {
            return "@BeforeMethod";
        }
        if (method.isAfterMethodConfiguration()) {
            return "@AfterMethod";
        }
        // Intentionally ignoring other config types for brevity
        return "@Test";
    }
}

Child class
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RestTests extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void testScenario1() {
        ITestResult tr = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        log(tr, methodType(tr), name(tr));
    }

    @Test
    public void testScenario2() {
        ITestResult tr = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        log(tr, methodType(tr), name(tr));
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult itrOfTestMethod) {
        ITestResult itrOfConfigMethod = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        log(itrOfTestMethod, methodType(itrOfConfigMethod), name(itrOfConfigMethod));
    }
}

Suite file
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="2980_suite" verbose="2">
    <test name="2980_test" parallel="methods">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.so.qn79190330.RestTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

Execution output
...
... TestNG 7.10.2 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

Feature name in @BeforeMethod annotated beforeMethod() = RestTests-65023d92-0795-4fd7-a32c-fc965eef66aa on thread 24
Feature name in @BeforeMethod annotated beforeMethod() = RestTests-88ed9611-fcd6-4e50-84fa-1e7f95d3e785 on thread 23
Feature name in @Test annotated testScenario1() = RestTests-88ed9611-fcd6-4e50-84fa-1e7f95d3e785 on thread 23
Feature name in @Test annotated testScenario2() = RestTests-65023d92-0795-4fd7-a32c-fc965eef66aa on thread 24
Feature name in @AfterMethod annotated afterMethod() = RestTests-65023d92-0795-4fd7-a32c-fc965eef66aa on thread 24
Feature name in @AfterMethod annotated afterMethod() = RestTests-88ed9611-fcd6-4e50-84fa-1e7f95d3e785 on thread 23
PASSED: com.rationaleemotions.so.qn79190330.RestTests.testScenario1
PASSED: com.rationaleemotions.so.qn79190330.RestTests.testScenario2

===============================================
    2980_test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
2980_suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

